# How to measure the PAPR of OFDM signal in practical case

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, signal-power

The way of investigating the PAPR for OFDM system using MATLAB is known, but what I am looking for is: can we measure the PAPR effect in real systems?

For example, assuming we have a transmitter and a receiver. let's assume we have optical system, where the signal is transmitted through light source to the receiver diode detector.  How can I know the PAPR of my signal?

Based on my searching on google, the simplest way is to use power meter to measure the average power of received signal and also the peak of signal after converting it into electrical. Then, calculate the PAPR.

honestly, I don't have power meter! so is there any other method to measure the PAPR for the real received signal?

Comment: I think the only practical way to do it is to digitize the received signal and do the calculation in discrete-time; e.g. with Matlab.

Comment: @MBaz Could you please explain the steps? you mean after I get the received signal, and then remove the guard interval. Then?  how about the channel effect? should it be removed ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to measure. The main point is that I don't see any benefit to trying to work with the continuous-time signal; all measurements can be done in discrete-time much more easily.

Comment: By the way, this is not always the case. For example, measuring the effective radiated power from an antenna is much easier in the analog domain. The reason is that, unless you're very careful, in the process of going from CT to DT and from passband to baseband, the true signal power is lost. However, you're trying to measure a power _ratio_, and ratios are preserved (as long as your system is linear, e.g. no clipping!).